# Sublime Text 3 - Sidebar Font Face Change

Tags: fonts, sublime-text-3

Is it possible to change font_face property in Sublime Text 3? I tried changing in `predawn.sublime-theme` theme file, section with `"class": sidebar_label` without success. I know this worked in version 2, it that changed somehow?

Comment: You actually got it working in Sublime Text 2? Do you remember exactly how you did it? Because I'm just trying to, and it just blanks out all the labels... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337160/how-do-you-change-the-font-face-sublime-uses-for-the-sidebar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You almost got it. In `"class": sidebar_label` just add a comma after the last entry and on the next line put the following:

```
"font.face": "Comic Sans"
```

(or whatever font you want). If the size is off, just add a comma and another line:

```
"font.size": 10
```

(or whatever size works).

Comment: Thanks. Where I was wrong is, that I tried with `font_face` instead of `font.face` ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is several `"class": sidebar_label`. First of all, set font.face and fon.size together or it craches! It's better to set it in the first of all "class": sidebar_label.
Example:

```
      // Bullet Tree Indicator

{
  "class": "tree_row",
  "settings": ["material_theme_bullet_tree_indicator"],
  "attributes": ["selected"],
  "layer1.texture": "Material Theme/assets/commons/tree_highlight--bullet.png",
  "layer1.inner_margin": [22, 16, 0, 0]
},

{
  "class": "sidebar_label",
  "color": [96, 125, 139],
  "font.bold": false,
  "font.italic": false,
  "font.face": "Fira Code Retina",
  "font.size": 8,
  "shadow_color": [255, 255, 255, 0],
  "shadow_offset": [0, 0]
},
...
```